# Calling Truffle Commands through a script

Tags: truffle, contract-invocation, truffle-contract, batch, truffle-console

I made following contract using visual studio code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract IDSCheck {

    mapping( string => string ) PersonHash;

    function AddHash(string name, string hash) {
        PersonHash[name] = hash;

    }

    function GetHash (string name) public returns (string) {
        return PersonHash[name];
    }
}
```

Now I want to call this function from truffle using exec command.

I wrote a js file named idscheck.js with the following commands

```
var IDSCheck = artifacts.require("./IDSCheck.sol");
module.exports = function (deployer) {
  var ss;
  IDSCheck.deployed().then(function(deployed){ ss=deployed; });
  ss.GetHash.call("sal");
}
```

I get an output error saying

> Type Error: cannot read property 'GetHash' of undefined at .....

I am trying to do this is in truffle console.
Primary target is to create a script that runs through a batch file using truffle console to get output of the GetHash function of the above contract.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the async behavior of promise returned by `IDSCheck.deployed()`. The variable `ss` might not be initialized if you call `ss.GetHash()` immediately after.

You can fix it by executing the call after you are sure it was intialized properly inside the `.then()` function.

```
var IDSCheck = artifacts.require("./IDSCheck.sol");
module.exports = function (callback) {
  var ss;
  IDSCheck.deployed().then(function(deployed){
    ss = deployed;
    // Here we are sure `ss` is initialized and it is safe to call `.GetHash()`
    ss.GetHash.call("sal");
  });
  // This code 'might' be excuted before the code inside `.then()`
  // ss.GetHash.call("sal");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
var IDSCheck = artifacts.require("./IDSCheck.sol");
```

To this:

```
var IDSCheck = artifacts.require("./IDSCheck.sol").new();
```

Comment: I changed but now new error is showing up .. TypeError: IDSCheck.deployed is not a function